# Botão para excluir form caso somente se não estiver preenchido

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Tenho um botão que adicionar novos forms de localizações. Gostaria de saber como faço para deletar o form caso tenha o adicionado ele não será preenchido.

Criei esse link para deletar os campos.

```
<div class="col-12 text-center">
  <div class="link_company blue underline_hover pointer" (click)="removeLocation()" i18n>Remover campos</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-12 text-center">
  <div class="link_company blue underline_hover pointer" (click)="removeLocation()" i18n>Remover campos</div>
</div>
```

faça uma função que é chamada quando for enviado o form, tipo uma validação aonde tenha o teste lógico.

```
if($(".col-12 text-center") == ''){
  removeLocation();
}
```

tipo desse jeito entendeu?

Comment: Não é bem isso, eu preciso criar a função de removeLocation() em um component.ts.

Comment: Caso o form esteja dirty o div de remover campo não estará visível, caso esteja pristine o div estará visivel para remover campo